# positioning picture on GUI JFrame in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, absolutelayout

I was wondering if there is a quick and easy way of trying to position an image at a particular position in GUI. In addition to this is it possible to put Jlables/Buttons on this picture. That picture should only form a section of the JFrame. I know you can use setbounds(width, height, width, height); but this takes alot of accuracy and very hard to get perfectly right.

Comment: If picture should form only a section of `JFrame` then why dont you create an `JPanel` inside that frame and set its background image to that picture

Comment: *"particular position in GUI."*  By what formula or logic is this position determined?

Answer (score 3):

Don't call `setBounds`, which implies that you are using a `null` layout. Always use a layout manager.

One approach would be to add a custom `JPanel` that overrides `paintComponent` and calls [`drawImage(Image, x, y, width, height, ...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29). `JLabels/JButtons`, etc. can still be added to the panel.

Don't forget to call `super.paintComponent`—this will ensure that your child components get painted.

Also, have a look at [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/).